# Phonegap/Cordova code keeps getting reset on build

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm starting to work on a PhoneGap/Cordova project  (focusing on Android for now). I'm trying to load a remote URL (and that seems to work fine, modified it in the Activity class (`loadUrl("http://10.0.3.2");`.  However, there are certain files and drawables, if I modify in my Assets folder for instance, get reset back to their original state. For instance, in index.js I'm changing the onDeviceReady method to do this:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
        alert(navigator.userAgent); // I've added this line and it alerts null anyway? 
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    },
```

When I run `phonegap run android`, the build that gets made will include that alert function but when I go back to my Editor (PHPStorm in this case), it will inform me that the file has been editted outside the IDE and when it gets reloaded my alert is no longer there. I've googled this repeatedly (PhoneGap resetting code on build; as well as other queries) but I can't find an answer to what's going on.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the files in the root www folders and not in the platform specific www folders (`platforms/android/assets/www`). Unless you code platform specific things. Java in this case.

When you build your app these platform specific folders and their content will be overwritten by the code from the root `www` folder.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. But what if I want Android or iOS specific code in there?

Comment: then you just edit the Java or Obj-C files directly in `platforms/android/src` or `platforms/ios/..` those files will not be overwritten.